# Replace the code in a text file and repeat the concatenated text for different strings

Tags: python, for-loop, concatenation

I have four files:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

and I have yet another file named `list.txt` containing different strings.
I want to replace the string "xxxxxxxx" in file3.txt
I have successfully concatenated the contents of all files in python and replaced the string in `file3.txt` and presented a new file named `output.txt`.

Below is my code:

```
import re

info1 = info2 = info3 = info4 = ""
# Reading information from the first file
with open('file1.txt') as file:
   info1 = file.read()

# Reading information from the second file
with open('file2.txt') as file:
   info2 = file.read()
    
# Reading information from the third file
with open('file3.txt') as file:
   info3 = file.read()

#Reading information from the list file
with open ('mylist.txt') as file:
    mylist = file.readlines()

for string in mylist:
    info3 = re.sub("xxxxxxxxxx", string, info3)
 
with open('file4.txt') as file:
     info4 = file.read()

info1 += info2
info2 += info3
info3 += info4

with open ('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(info1)
    file.write(info3)
```

However, I am getting only one instance of the concatenated file.
E.g.

```
content of file1.txt = Hello World
content of file2.txt = My name is Darth Vader
content of file3.txt = I have come to invade xxxxxxxxxx
Content of file4.txt = If you only knew the power of dark side. 

Content of list.txt = 
tatooine 
coruscant 
hoth
bespin
```

Got the output in `output.txt`:

```
Hello World
My name is Darth Vader 
I have come to invade tatooine
If you only knew the power of dark side.
```

However, the desired output is: (it should have file1.txt echoed only once)

```
Hello World
My name is Darth Vader 
I have come to invade tatooine
If you only knew the power of dark side.
My name is Darth Vader 
I have come to invade coruscant
If you only knew the power of dark side.
My name is Darth Vader 
I have come to invade hoth
If you only knew the power of dark side.
My name is Darth Vader 
I have come to invade bespin
If you only knew the power of dark side.
```

I am sure I am missing the sequence of for loop, resulting to stop it in spite of several strings in the file3.txt. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling re.sub repeatedly? If the pattern "xxxxxxxxxx" exists it will be replaced by the first line in mylist.txt (including trailing newline which you probably don't want). Subsequent iterations will just be a waste of time. Maybe mylist.txt only contains 1 line

Answer (score 1):

Like you have mentioned in your question, you need to do some changes in your loop.

This is a modified version of your code which produces the required output. There are different ways (and probably even better ways) to get the same result, but this solution is kept as close as possible to your original code in the question:

```py
import re

info1 = info2 = info3 = info4 = ""
# Reading information from the first file
with open("file1.txt") as file:
    info1 = file.read()

# Reading information from the second file
with open("file2.txt") as file:
    info2 = file.read()

# Reading information from the third file
with open("file3.txt") as file:
    info3 = file.read()

# Reading information from the fourth file
with open("file4.txt") as file:
    info4 = file.read()

# Reading information from the list file
with open("mylist.txt") as file:
    mylist = file.readlines()

# Open the output file for writing
with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
   # generate the full text for every string in the list and write to the file
   file.write(info1)
   for string in mylist:
      replaced_info3 = re.sub("xxxxxxxxxx", string, info3)
      file_contents = info2 + replaced_info3 + info4
      file.write(file_contents)
```

In the original question, the value of `info3` would be replaced losing the string template. After the first iteration of the loop, the value would have been `I have come to invade tatooine`. And in every other iteration of the loop no value will be replaced since `info3` would no longer contain the text `xxxxxxxxxx`. In the answer, instead a new variable `replaced_info3` is used so that the original template of the text (`info3`) is not lost.

We're opening the file and looping while the file is open to generate new text and write that inside the file. Since we want to repeat the operation multiple times, we cannot modify the variables which contain the original text and instead store the results in a new variable (it's also better not to modify the original variables and use a separate variable with a meaningful name to improve the code).

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**: Updated code to add contents of file1 to the output only once. Previous version of the code repeated file1 contents along with other files

Comment: Did you test this? Consider what happens if mylist.txt contains more than one line

Comment: @DarkKnight I had tested this with the exact same inputs in the question, a file (mylist.txt) containing 4 lines and got the desired output. The code uses `readlines` just like the question to put separate lines of the file contents into mylist as a list

Answer (score 0):

The substitution of 'xxxxxxxxxx' with the contents of mylist.txt will only be affected by the first line of that file - i.e., the loop around re.sub() is pointless.

A better structure would be to open the output file first then process the files from a list.

Something like this:

```
# the input files
files = [
    'file1.txt',
    'file2.txt',
    'file3.txt',
    'file4.txt'
    ]
# use a set here in case you want to add more files
replace_in = {'file3.txt'}
# the file containing (one line of) substitution data
sub = 'mylist.txt'
# the output target
output = 'output.txt'

with open(output, 'w') as out:
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as indata:
            content = indata.read()
            if file in replace_in:
                with open(sub) as subs:
                    out.write(content.replace('xxxxxxxxxx', subs.readline().rstrip()))
            else:
                out.write(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re

infiles = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt", "list.txt"]
content = [Path(file).read_text().rstrip() for file in infiles]
template = f"{content[1]}\n{{}}\n{content[3]}"
out = content[0] + "\n" + "\n".join(
    template.format(re.sub("xxxxxxxxxx", repl, content[2]))
    for repl in content[-1].splitlines(keepends=False)
)
Path("output.txt").write_text(out)
```

Result for the sample:

```
Hello World
My name is Darth Vader
I have come to invade tatooine 
If you only knew the power of dark side.
My name is Darth Vader
I have come to invade coruscant 
If you only knew the power of dark side.
My name is Darth Vader
I have come to invade hoth
If you only knew the power of dark side.
My name is Darth Vader
I have come to invade bespin
If you only knew the power of dark side.
```

I'm not sure you really need `re`, at least for the sample this

```py
    ...
    template.format(content[2].replace("xxxxxxxxxx", repl))
    ...
```

would do the same.